# Cell does not get deselected while scrolled back

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a weird problem. While I select a cell with changing the background color of one UIView component, then I scroll down and selected cell going to be out of bounds of the view. I do select new cell -> previous one should get unselected, but it does not. Because when I back I do have 2 selected cells.

```
var lastSelectedAtIndexPath: IndexPath?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch tableView {
        case myTableView:

            if let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {
                cell.checkMarkBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGreyFts
                lastSelectedFuelAtIndexPath = indexPath
            }

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch tableView {
        case myTableView:

            if let cell = fuelTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {
                cell.checkMarkBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }

        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

And iside `cellForRowAt` I have :

```
        let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as! MyTableViewCell


if let lastIndexPath = lastSelectedFuelAtIndexPath {
                myTableView.deselectRow(at: lastIndexPath, animated: true)
            }

        cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: fuelType)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        cell.myNameLabel.text = "Test"
```

Any ideas what is going on? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you having multiple tableView ?

Comment: @NiravD Yes, I do have. The biggest problem is that if I select cell at index path row = 0 and then I scroll down - to select new cell I have to tap 2 times.

Comment: Show some more code from `cellForRowAt` method also what happend when you select a cell that is already selected? Does it need to deselect ?

Comment: 'cellForRowAt' only fils couple of the components. One is adding an image to the image view, second is adding text to the label. Basically there is nothing else. I will update the question. I would like to selecting items and then after picking new once deselecting old one and selecting new one.

Comment: I get that but what happen when you select cell that is already selected does it need to deselect ?

Comment: Only when we select new one. I was trying something which does not work as well with 'myTableView.deselectRow'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make changes on cell outside `cellForRowAt` always change your dataSource and use dataSource in `cellForRowAt` then in `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeSelectRowAt` reload the row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: fuelType)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    cell.myNameLabel.text = "Test"
    cell.checkMarkBorder.backgroundColor = lastSelectedFuelAtIndexPath == indexPath ? UIColor.darkGreyFts : UIColor.white
    return cell
}
```

Now in `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeSelectRowAt` update the `lastSelectedFuelAtIndexPath` reload the row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == myTableView {           
        lastSelectedFuelAtIndexPath = indexPath
        myTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == myTableView {
        lastSelectedFuelAtIndexPath = nil
        myTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: What about needed double tap to select new cell while we scroll down and previous selected cell is out of bounds ? Because it only occurs when the previous selected cell is out of bounds of the view.

Comment: @yerpy Try this solution first It will sure solved the problem of double tap also the issue you are facing is because of reuse of cell

Comment: OK, Thank you for your help.

Comment: @yerpy Welcome mate :)